# Darken image on mouseover: black bar above the image

Tags: html, css

I'm using the css code:

```
a.darken img {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

and the html code:

```
<a class="darken" href="http://sussexbaptist.byethost7.com/sunday/">
  <img src="http://sussexbaptist.byethost7.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
</a>
```

The darken effect works fine, but there is a black bar coming out above the image. Can someone help me fix this?

if you want to see a live example of my problem my website is http://www.sussexbaptist.byethost7.com

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue with the code provided. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8L75pbzt/

Comment: Does the black bar appear all the time or only when you hover?  When you say "above the image", do you mean in the y-direction or the z-direction?

Comment: Could it be that (because of some other piece of CSS) your image is getting a top `margin` or `padding`? For example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/2j5gspx1/)

Comment: if you guys want to see the problem in action my webiste is http://www.sussexbaptist.byethost7.com